# Extract all tables from an SQL query

Tags: php, regex

I want to add a prefix to tables and have recently written a PHP script to extract all tables in a string SQL query.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE festivals SET desc = "Starts from July"';
preg_match_all('/(from|into|update|table|join) (`?\w+`?)\s/i', $sql, $matches);
```

It works good but the only problem is that it extracts `July` because it does not distinguish between a SQL value and a real table name, so it assumes that `July` would be a table too.

Now I think the solution should be something to prevent extract what wrapped in a single or double quotation but don't know how to do that.

Comment: You should really consider this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281041/regular-expression-to-find-all-table-names-in-a-query.

Comment: Thanks, but that's another issue because i want to add a prefix to tables and don't care about white spaces, aliases or etc.

Comment: did you try the regex I suggested below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is better off this way:

```
"/((?:^select .+?(?:from|into))|^update|^table|join) (`?\w+`?)\s/I"
```

But I still agree with nvartolomei.

Comment: It's working for your test case in ruby flavor. What flavor are you using?

Comment: i don't know how to make a room, but this is my yahoo id `lwl_kahroba_lwl`, also available ok skype as `omidamraei`

Comment: [Here you go](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18012/extract-all-tables-from-an-sql-query-chat)

Answer (score 0):

If you were more strict in your query-writing, you would wrap all your database, table and column names in backticks `` ` `` and they would be extremely easy to extract - just get the first match of a string between them: just make the backticks required instead of optional.

That said, I'm not entirely sure how your regex is matching `from July` since the `July` is not followed by whitespace...

Comment: true, didn't pick that up. maybe he didn't actually test it and is just presenting a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: @Kolink Using backticks would be a good idea but just when you are the only developer and not applicable for teamwork. And about `July` this is just an example

Comment: If you (or your team) can't follow proper standards, then you can't process the task with a regular expression. You would have more luck parsing the query yourself and extracting the tables. Alternatively, you might be able to put `explain` at the start of the query, run it, and then look for the tables listed in the query summary.