# complex regex C# or perl

Tags: c#, regex, perl, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I have the following SQL text in a file. the objective is to identify database tables names from the files. Below is just a generic example and I am looking for a generic solution, either in C# or Perl. I am not done lot of regex therefore I would appreciate if someone gives me a start

```
select
a.xyz,
b.xyz,c.xyz,
d.xyz
from db1.test1 a
inner join db2.test2 b
on a.xyz = b.xyz
inner join
(
select a.xyz
from db1.test3) as c
on a.xyz=c.xyz
left outer join db1.test4 d
on c.xyz = d.xyz
```

so basically, i need to automate finding out names of all tables in the SQL. in this case, test1, test2, test3 and test4

I know that pattern is the tables names are preceded by either "from" , "inner join", "left outer join" , then a databasename (such as db1, db2 etc) , then a literal '.' and the table name.

Answer (score 2):

This is C# code that will find your table names in the example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(yourString, @"(from|inner\s+join|left\s+outer\s+join)\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\.\s*(?<table>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*\.\s*(?<table>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)*", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups["table"].Captures)
    {
        string tableName = capture.Value;
    }
}
```

The same regex will at least get you pointed in the right direction in Perl, as regex is mostly cross-compatible.

Edit: Updated to (clumsily?) find multiple tables separated by commas, and incorporate Alan's suggestions to use `"table"` to find the groups and mark `ExplicitCapture`.  If you run into many more problems, you might want to do as suggested in [Regular expression to find all table names in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281041/regular-expression-to-find-all-table-names-in-a-query) and find a SQL parser instead of trying to use regex.

Comment: thanks Tim, there is one other pattern that I may encounter, for example, I could have a pattern like this "from db1.test5, db1.test6"
. In this case, i want to capture but test5 and test6. However I see that I can capture on test5 (based on above code). is there any way to match both test5 and test6

Comment: +1, but you should use `Groups["table"]`, not `Groups[2]`.  To see why, add this to the end of your regex: `(?:\s+(\w+))?`.  You should find that `Group[2]` now contains the table alias (`a`, `b`, or `d`), and `Groups["table"]` is the same as `Groups[3]`.  It's never a good idea to use named groups and numbered groups in the same regex.  In fact, if you use named groups you should set the ExplicitCapture flag to disable numbered groups.