# Get used tables from sql query

Tags: c#, sql

I need extract from simple string that represent an sql query the tables that are used on the query without execute the query itself in C#.

Example:

```
string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2) tt WHERE tt.name IN (SELECT name FROM table3)";
ArrayList arrUsedTables = GetUsedTablesFromQuery(strQuery);
```

and after this line the object `arrUsedTables` would contain:
`table1`,`table2`,`table3`

Remember that the query may be much complicated!

Comment: What ahve you tried so far?

Comment: I would suggest to use regex, however.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/281059/284240

Comment: You need a SQL parser for .Net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net

Comment: @Andreas That link is a closed question with dead links and for Java

Comment: @AaronMcIver http://www.antlr4.org is cross platform, the question was asked for Java but the provided solution is valid for C# as well. I did not check the link, sorry for that from my side.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you could execute the query but with FMTONLY option, that would only parse the SQL and return the column information. No rows will be affected.

Comment: @jure -- think that will only return the structure of the resultset? You can ask sql server to deliver an "Estimated Query Plan" which will contain all the base tables (I think) -- however I have no idea if it's possible to ask for that via ado.net or linq

Answer (score 4):

Without going to the DB **you can't know for certain** the names of the **tables** used in the query.

What if your query uses a view or a stored procedure?

Without consulting the database, these are transparent to the consumer.

The only way to be certain is to query the list of the tables from the database and **then** to attempt to parse them from your inline sql.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add references and directives for the following assemblies:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom;
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql;
using System.IO;
```

Then, you may create the `GetUsedTablesFromQuery` method:

```
private static ArrayList GetUsedTablesFromQuery(string strQuery)
{
    var parser = new TSql100Parser(true);
    IList<ParseError> errors = new List<ParseError>();
    using (TextReader r = new StringReader(strQuery))
    {
        var result = parser.GetTokenStream(r, out errors);
        var tables = result
            .Select((i, index) => (i.TokenType == TSqlTokenType.From) ? result[index + 2].Text : null)
            .Where(i => i != null)
            .ToArray();

        return new ArrayList(tables);
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom has been replaced with [Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013135/microsoft-data-schema-scriptdom-with-vs2012-ultimate).  I found the dll at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll`.  (You do not need the .Sql namespace when using the new namespace/dll.

Comment: So I tried to get the example to work and ran into a number of problems so I came up with my own version which I cannot post here since they locked it (not really a dup since this one requires C# but whatever).  You can find my solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25778275/641833

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use a SQL parser such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), as described in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net), in order to get a full parse of the SQL, and then extract the table names.

Another option is to execute some raw SQL to get the execution plan of the query (using the instructions [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/21/sql-server-get-query-plan-along-with-query-text-and-execution-count/)).  The execution plan is in XML, and then you can use Linq to XML to query the plan for all `Table` attributes on any `ColumnReference` tag.