# Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom with VS2012 Ultimate

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Does Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom ship with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate?

I am trying to load a Visual Studio 2010 project that referenced this assembly and since moving to VS2012 (on a different PC) it can no longer find this assembly.

I thought VS2012 Ultimate had *everything*, so where has this assembly gone?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have resolved this myself after discovering that Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom has been superseded by Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, which is deployed along with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I found the file at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll`.

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom isn't backward compatible with Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.dll

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, my project was referring to the following assembly

`<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`

I had visual studio 2012 **only** and I found the assemblies (Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.dll) in the following folder,

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSTSDB

Changing the assembly version solved the issue for me.

`<Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />`

it is part of visual studio, so one has to install visual studio 2010 if they want version 10.0.0.0