# Get name of all the tables used in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have dynamic SQL statement generated using criteria. This statement involves multiple joins using many tables. Requirement is to get list of all the tables used in this statement.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    table1.a, table2.b, ... 
FROM 
    table1 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.col1 = table2.col1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.col3 = table3.col1
```

I want to get list of tables used in the above query dynamically like:

```
table1,table2,table3.
```

I am using C# and SQL Server. I think parsing the string and finding individual tables will be complex. Is there any way we can get the list of Tables used in a query from SQL Server itself?

Comment: Can you show how are you generating those statements? Are you generating it by yor code or receive from somewhere?

Comment: Your query syntax appears to be incorrect: In the `SELECT` clause, `a` and `b` are column names. In the `JOIN` clauses, they are suddenly table names or aliases.

Comment: We have GUI which generates and saves the query. We don't want to persist the tables used during the mapping itself.

Comment: If the GUI generates the query, can't it also be made to generate a list with just the table names?

Comment: Like I mentioned above,report query is saved and used later.  don't want to save the joined tables as well.

Comment: This was answered by Alex Filipovici in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16927153/get-used-tables-from-sql-query