# Javascript regex - how to match when no trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

[In this regex](http://regexr.com/3b0s9) I'm trying to extract the list of tables from a SQL select statement. It works fine with one exception, if the statement ends with the table name there is no match. For example:

Given he regex:

```
(?:from|join)\s+(.*?)(?:\)|\s+(?:where|on|inner|outer|full|left|right|join|\s*$))
```

and given this string:

```
"select xxxx  from table1 t1, table2, table3 t3 "  (note the last space)
```

The match is:

```
"table1 t1, table2, table3 t3"
```

But given this string:

```
"select xxxx  from table1 t1, table2, table3 t3"  (without last space)
```

There's no match. How to make this work?

Comment: Wow, that's going to be tough. What about fully-qualified, escaped table names like `[DataBase].[dbo].[TableName]` (SQL Server) or `\`TableName\`` in MySQL (just for two examples your regex won't hit). Subqueries as well (`select * from (select * from table)`). I'm afraid regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

Comment: I would rather parse it that try to match it (not saying it's not possible but this would need some work at least)

Comment: SQL is not a regular language so... parse it. Keep your sanity. Don't follow Cthulu. ;)

Comment: I just need the table names, do I still need to parse it? if yes, how to do that?

Comment: Can you guarantee that your input will stay simple? For instance, might you have to extract the tables from something of the form `select count(*) from ( select foo.bar, baz.foo from foo, (select foo from herp) baz)`? If so, matching just won't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx isn't very good at this, as it's a lot more complicated than it appears:

- What if they use LEFT/RIGHT INNER/OUTER/CROSS/MERGE/NATURAL joins instead of the a,b syntax?  The a,b syntax should be avoided anyway.
- What about nested queries?
- What if there is no table (selecting a constant)
- What about line breaks and other whitespace formatting?
- Alias names?

What you can do is an sql parser, and there is a good one [Hrer](http://www.sqlparser.com/).

See more answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281041/regular-expression-to-find-all-table-names-in-a-query).

Comment: Just to be clear - it is the second `\s` that is the problem, so `|\s+(?:where|...` should really become `|\s*(?:where|...`

Comment: exactly the second one

Comment: I cannot make that change as `from tablewhere` would become a match and it should not

Comment: @pgschr your'r right and after some searching i updated my answer.