# How to parse SQL query to get table names involved in that query in Access

Tags: regex, vba, parsing, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have decided to solve this problem by using vba and regular expression. Here is part of the code:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "(FROM|JOIN|from|From|Join|join)\s+([^ ,]+)(?:\s*,\s*([^ ,]+))*\s*"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strInput As String

Set MyMatches = regEx.Execute(Form)

If MyMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    With MyMatches
        For myMatchCt = 0 To MyMatches.Count - 1
            If Left(MyMatches.Item(myMatchCt), 6) <> "FROM (" And Left(MyMatches.Item(myMatchCt), 6) <> "JOIN (" Then              
                str = MyMatches.Item(myMatchCt)
                lenght = Len(str)
                format_data = Right(str, lenght - 4)
                pos = InStr(format_data, ")") + InStr(format_data, "(select")
                If pos = 0 Then
                    rst.AddNew
                    rst!block_id = rs("block_id")
                    rst!trans_table = format_data
                    rst.Update
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End if
```

Parsed tables are written to `rst`.

It works almost fine with many types of query, I interested only in `select` queries. However I can't figure out how to handle subqueries, for example from this query I get odd bracket `(`:

```
select *
from (
select * from t1
union 
select * from t2
) t
where 1=1;
```

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance...

```
Left(MyMatches.Item(myMatchCt), 6) <> "FROM ("
```

<> is case sensitive

ie  this is true
     Left("From (", 6) <> "FROM ("

You will need to change it to

```
Ucase(Left(MyMatches.Item(myMatchCt), 6)) <> "FROM ("
```

Similarly with the "JOIN" condition

I can see why you want to write your own code as buying SQL parsers is expensive!

Here's some text and links I found about this:

Please also see this SO questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281041/regular-expression-to-find-all-table-names-in-a-query) which states:

RegEx isn't very good at this, as it's a lot more complicated than it appears:

What if they use LEFT/RIGHT INNER/OUTER/CROSS/MERGE/NATURAL joins instead of the a,b syntax? The a,b syntax should be avoided anyway.
What about nested queries?
What if there is no table (selecting a constant)
What about line breaks and other whitespace formatting?
Alias names?
I could go on.

What you can do is look for an sql parser, and run your query through that.

Also note: 
You want access to arbitrary substructures of a SQL query (including sub SELECTs)? What you need is a full parser for the SQL dialect of interest.

Try [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+parser+for+vba&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=Ot8SVtTEJcGOa8vAqugL#q=sql+parser+for+access+sql)

[This one](http://www.sqlparser.com/access-sql-parser.php) will set you back $400!  I'm starting to see why you are writing one - nice by the way.

SQL is a pretty large and complicated language. It is possible to hand-code a recursive descent parser to do this, but that's quite a lot of work. You'd be likely better off with a parser generator and an SQL BNF to feed it.

Comment: PS.  I read that this shareware Access VBA based framework (for $60) https://www.arrow-of-time.com/AXF.aspx has a SQL parser in it.  I've not used it though.